# un gzip multiple files?

Tags: linux, command-line, gzip, batch-processing

Ok I have a directory with N number of directories inside.. each of them has a list of jpg files on it... the problem is that I dont know how my brother did it but all files got gziped individually and now I cant read them as jpg files .. can you help me to return all the in to jpg files... heres an excample ..

```
thumbs/0000010295/
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-03.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-04.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-10.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-07.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-05.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-12.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-02.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-08.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-09.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-11.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000010295/0000010295-06.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-01.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-17.jpg.gz  
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-11.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-04.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-02.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-19.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-10.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-15.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-07.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-03.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-16.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-13.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-14.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-09.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-12.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-06.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-18.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-05.jpg.gz
thumbs/0000007757/0000007757-08.jpg.gz
```

and so on...

can you help me?? I need al get back to jpg and remove the .gz copy.. and yes all are compresed as .gz files I downloaded and un compresed fine.. so they wherent renamed just compressed

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few ways to do it. Here's one

```
find -name \*.gz | xargs -i gunzip {}
```